# Skip "square chars" from edit on OnKeyDown with Ctrl+BkSp

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I wrote an TEdit OnKeyDown handler to make custom <kbd>Ctrl+BkSp</kbd> handling. In my example i delete last 2 chars. Seen bad behaviour: after my code "square" char appended to text. How to not "add" such square?

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (key=vk_back) and (shift=[ssCtrl]) then
  begin
    with edit1 do
    begin
      if text<>'' then
        text:= Copy(text, 1, length(text)-2);
      selstart:= length(text);  
    end;
    key:= 0;
    Exit
  end;  
end;
```

Comment: Are you sure any of your code is really running? What you describe appears to be [what ordinary edit controls do already](http://superuser.com/q/332026/9291), which suggests that what you're seeing has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: @Rob. Sure. My code runs, it deletes last 2 chars. after, OS adds "square" char at end. What for my code needed? i want custom Ctrl+BkSp behavious as "default" SHAutoComplete method doesn't work- coz of some reason- i followed docu to call SHAutoComplete but Ctrl+BkSp not handled.

Comment: SHAutoComplete works. You are doing it wrong. Probably window recreation. You've got to call it in overridden CreateWnd.

Comment: Not really related to the issue, but the `Exit` at the end is very superfluous. Also, the test `text<>''` can safely be removed. Finally, ideally `Shift+Ctrl+BkSp` should also work, so replace `Shift = [ssCtrl]` with `ssCtrl in Shift`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple to way make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>BkSp</kbd> remove the two last characters:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin

  if Key = #127 then
  begin    
    Edit1.Text := Copy(Edit1.Text, 1, Length(Edit1.Text) - 2);
    Edit1.SelStart := Length(Edit1.Text);    
    Key := #0;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Please add a comment how `#127` is equivalent to `Ctrl+BkSp`